# handle wildcard in domain mapping route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have created a hosted zone with domain name "local-dev.com". In this domain if i register any application with test.local-dev.com or test-dev.local-dev.com it works fine. But if specify test.prod.local-dev.com then application is launched but it asks me to click on proceed or click on advanced option to proceed. How to handle this wildcard entries.

Comment: You will need to enter each subdomain as a cname within route53.
If your subdomains are pointed to the same ec2 instance, you will need to configure the server (apache, nginx, other) to route to the correct directory. ("virtual host" is the key word)

Comment: okay so if i want dev.application1.test.local-dev.com so first i will create CNAME type record for application1.test.local-dev.com then create A type record for dev.application1.test.local-dev.com

Comment: And yes all subdomains points to same ec2-instance

Comment: @MattBunch note that Route53 supports wildcard entries, so "each subdomain" is not a requirement.

Comment: @dharmeshmehta your question seems to imply that there is an SSL warning, and potentially multiple levels of wildcard matching.  Please review your question for thoroughness and see if you may have omitted important details.

Comment: yes, in my case multiple levels of wildcard matching needed which i'm was not able to figure out until i got one answer from @Matt Bunch. Applications are getting launched on https, so when currently i provide multiple level sub-domain it show ssl issue and ask to like on proceed anyway

Answer (score 1):

A Record: mysite.com -> ipaddress

CName: sub.mysite.com -> mysite.com

If your ip address ever changes, you will only need to update your A Record.

Within apache route the sub.mysite.com to the correct folder.
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html

```
<VirtualHost *:'the port of your node application'>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example1"
    ServerName www.example.com

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: please correct me if i'm wrong. In my case Type A local-dev.com in value ip-address then Type CNAME in value application1.test.local-dev.com

Comment: i am using apache

Comment: a record is the ip. correct. the cname should have the value 'local-dev.com'

Comment: okay i understood. one last scenario if i want launch multiple application one after the other. In that case then my Type A record ip-address should change to that corresponding application

Comment: @dharmeshmehta if you want each application to have its own subdomain, they will all point to the same A record. You will handle the routing of each subdomain within apache virtual hosts.

Comment: yes virtual host. Can i get any example for virtual host